# Rails Create and Use Calculated Field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I am trying to create a field in my model that concatenates two other fields. I would like this done outside the controller code because this field will be used on many occasions.

I have the code below but it is not working.

In Program Controller:

```
@test = Program.pluck(:program_detail)
```

In Program model:

```
...
has_many :versions

private
  def program_detail
    [owner, name].join(' - ')
  end
...
```

**Note I am using mongoid meaning I don't need to use migrations, but a Rails activerecord answer will definitely be enough to get me going.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pluck` only works on database columns, not on attributes in your model class. You can however retrieve all the records and to this.

```
Lane.where(..something..).map(&:program_detail)
```

Will give you an array of `program_detail`'s

Comment: So, to create a new calculated column is the best practice to just to do it in the controller on the create action?

Comment: Why in the controller? The concatenation logic is in the model. Now you can use the  `program_detail` method everywhere. Do not forget to make it `public`.

Comment: By all means put it in the model, that's the right place.

Comment: But what if I actually want to create a hard coded column in the database. That way there is no recalculation every time it is used, where is the best place to create that?

Comment: That is beyond the scope of this question. You should create a new question here for that. However a simple string concatenation is not a very expensive operation so I see no harm in having that in the model as it is now.